# how to estimate heterogeneous effects?

Tags: regression-discontinuity

I have a dataset where I run regression discontinuity with the following code:

xi: reg work post i.post|m i.post|m2 age age2 age3 immig primary hsgrad univ sib pleave i.q if m>-10 & m<9, robust

How where primary hsgrad univ are regressors referring to the educational status. How can I do the same regression but only for subjects that have university completed? (univ is a dummy variable==1 if subject has university). Do I need to remove the other regressors referring to education from the equation?

Comment: is this Stata code?

Answer (score 1):

Run this in Stata:

```
xi: reg work post i.post|m i.post|m2 age age2 age3 immig sib pleave i.q \\\
    if m>-10 & m<9 & univ==1, robust
```

You should remove the education regressors when doing this. The `univ` regressor needs to be removed since it will only take the value 1 when restricting to `univ==1`, so it will be perfectly colinear with the constant term. You need to remove the `primary` and `hsgrad` variables since those will become zero columns in the data matrix and will be (trivially) perfectly colinear with any other variable.